# Should security privileges be linked to the object or user in a document base database?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, security

I am currently working on roles and privileges on a Spring Boot back-end.
I'm facing a problem, so I thought someone could give me some advice.

Problem:
I need to check the user privileges for a specific resource in my database to authorize or not the access to it. I have 2 documents in my MongoDB repository, User and Dashboard.

Maybe an example might be more clearer

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id , 'Dashboard', 'READ')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboards/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Dashboard getDashboard(@PathVariable("id") int id);
```

A request in my controller interface looks like that.
My issue is where should I store the privileges ?

I though about having a `Map<String, PrivilegeType> privileges` (where String is the Id of a user and PrivilegeType is an enum) in my Dashboard Entity. That way I can easily manage the privileges if they need to be updated for a specific dashboard.

But before the controller can manager the request, the Permission Evaluator need to get the dashboard from the repository to retrieve all the privileges on that object to tell if an user can access to that specific dashboard.

And finally, if the security part approved, the controller will manage the request and retrieve one more time the dashboard. There is a lot of duplication of queries.

So I don't know if the privileges should be coupled to the user or if they should be linked to the targeted resource.

It is MongoDB, if it was a relational database, the question was not a problem but here I am not sure.

In my point of view:

Store the privileges into the Dashboard documents

- pros : easy to update all the privileges for a dashboard (replace all the map<UserID,Privileges> on a request)
- cons : need to fetch the dashboard when a user make a request to check the privileges

Store the privileges into the User documents

- pros : only need the user to verify the privileges
- cons : when I update the dashboard privileges, need to retrieve each user one by one in order to modify there own mapping (e.g. Map<dashboardId,Privilege>)

I hope that everything is clear, I have not found an answer yet and I thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I had to retrofit similar requirement sometime back but it wasn't spring boot but conceptually same. I.e some rules are run to decide what resource user is accessing and and the relationship of the user to that resource to decide the permissions to grant to this particular user for that resource.
- I would go with storing the permissions as part of the `dashboard` document for the following reasons

  - Even if it is a repeated query, database will return it quickly because of caching on the database side itself as query that was executed a few milli seconds ago.
  - If performance becomes an issue and want to stop second call altogether, I can later consider creating a `ThreadLocal` request context in my permission evaluator, and then I can tweak my my controller to check first if the resource is already in the `ThreadLocal` request context.

**Note**

- There is another reason we went with running rule in filter and granting dynamic privileges and then annotating the method with to check if the principal has that dynamic privilege. In addition to allowing access to the method, we also show or hide sections in the response based on privilege. That means the rule has to run again when preparing the response in addition to checking at the entrance. By running the rule once in the filter and enhancing the principal's static role based privileges with dynamic privileges, we only run the rule once

Comment: I see, thank you, it helps me for my decision-making. I will go with the privileges in the dashboard. Also I discovered I can use `PostAuthorize`,it can be useful if it is only a get request. Like that I retrieve the resource only once. But for other use case, I will use a `PreAuthorize`.